# Creating a percentage bar with Java and iText

Tags: java, itext

I'm a developer on a larger web application in which I've implemented a system to create and answer questionnaires. To review the results, it looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to make a printable report with iText, which should look pretty much the same. But I have no clue how to make the percentagebars with iText.
If it's possible it should have the same greenish image background, and then a solid color showing the % on top of that.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out these examples:

http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=10

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :-)  I have been poking around the "iText in Action" book, but I haven't got much experience working with iText. I kind of hoped that I could set both a background image AND a foreground color on a cell/rectangle/some component. Maybe someone tried to do this before?